# ios rightBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uikit, storyboard

I have a `UITabBarController` which is the second item inside a `UINavigationController`.

Each item within the `UITabBarController` is a sub class of `UIViewController`. How can I create a button that appears at the top right of the navigationBar and changes depending on which tab is selected.

I am using `storyboards`, just in case there is a gui way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the UITabBarControllerDelegate method tabBarController:didSelectViewController: and then depending on what view controller was selected set the rightBarButtonItem of your UINavigationController to show whatever you want it to show.